# Get form data in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple form in my `render` function, like so:

```
render : function() {
      return (
        <form>
          <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
          <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
          <button type="button" onClick={this.handleLogin}>Login</button>
        </form>
      );
    },
handleLogin: function() {
   // How can I access email and password here?
}
```

What should I write in my `handleLogin: function() { ... }` to access `Email` and `Password` fields?

Comment: Note: you should handle `onSubmit` on the form rather than the button click - this way you will also handle the user submitting the form by pressing enter.

Comment: A `<form>` with a `<button>` or `<input>` with `type=submit` will get submitted when the user presses Enter in any of the form's `<input type=text>`. If you rely on an `onClick` of a button, the user must click the button or focus it and press Enter/Spacebar. Using `onSubmit` will enable both use cases. When forms don't support Enter to submit, they can feel broken.

Comment: there is also the benefit of browser's native checking on empty values of required fields

Answer (score 228, accepted):

Use the `change` events on the inputs to update the component's state and access it in `handleLogin`:

```
handleEmailChange: function(e) {
   this.setState({email: e.target.value});
},
handlePasswordChange: function(e) {
   this.setState({password: e.target.value});
},
render : function() {
      return (
        <form>
          <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleEmailChange} />
          <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handlePasswordChange}/>
          <button type="button" onClick={this.handleLogin}>Login</button>
        </form>);
},
handleLogin: function() {
    console.log("EMail: " + this.state.email);
    console.log("Password: " + this.state.password);
}
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kTu3a/).

Also, read the docs, there is a whole section dedicated to form handling: [Forms](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html)

Previously you could also use React's two-way databinding helper mixin to achieve the same thing, but now it's deprecated in favor of setting the value and change handler (as above):

```
var ExampleForm = React.createClass({
  mixins: [React.addons.LinkedStateMixin],
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {email: '', password: ''};
  },
  handleLogin: function() {
    console.log("EMail: " + this.state.email);
    console.log("Password: " + this.state.password);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input type="text" valueLink={this.linkState('email')} />
        <input type="password" valueLink={this.linkState('password')} />
        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleLogin}>Login</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
});
```

Documentation is here: [Two-way Binding Helpers](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html).

Comment: What are the pros and cons of going with `onchange` v/s going with mixin ?

Comment: I think it's not really promoted in the docs since React's model of dataflow is more like 'one-way databinding' and users are encouraged to think more in these terms. That being said, the docs themselves acknowledge that ReactLink is purely syntactic sugar for the 'onChange'/'setState' way of doing it.

Comment: To correctly mimic the functionality of `valueLink`, your first example should set the `value` of the input elements. Without that, the values are ["uncontrolled"](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#uncontrolled-components) in React terms. `<input ... value={this.state.password}>`.

Comment: The mixin method gives me the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'LinkedStateMixin' of undefined `

Comment: You need to use the React build with addons (`react-with-addons.js`)

Comment: you can also use an onSubmit with the form instead of onClick with the button

Comment: What if I wan to use an uncontrolled input? @jbaiter

Comment: Controlled Components have potential issues with autocomplete. Ref https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1159 and https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2125

Comment: how to achieve via ES6 react Component way.

Comment: Why using a state for each element of the form ? 
Anyone else thinks this is a bad pattern ?

Comment: Looks like valueLink is deprecated

Comment: commenting from the future to thank @MattBroekhuis for saving me time on valueLink

Comment: Isn't this storing the password in clear text on the client side for the whole time? That doesn't seem really appropriate for a password field.

Comment: The downside of this approach is that you're causing a state change everytime the value of the inputs change. If you only need the values when the user submits the form, you should not go with this approach.

Comment: as `this.setState` is asynchrnous, is it possible that the `handleLogin` doesn't retrieve the last value of `this.state.login` or `this.state.password` ? Imagine the user is writing his password and submit immediatly the form, if `setState` is asynchronous it may be executed after the `onSubmit` handler ?

Comment: If I am using redux, it it fine to create a state in component?

Comment: Is there performance impact on re-rendering? @hoohoo-b answer prevents re-rendering.

Comment: the purpose of <form> is so you can use e.target.elements, and html build in required props etc, if you are using state, then <form> is redundant.

Comment: Ah, so this is why React forms sometimes reset themselves after autofill race conditions. Thank you for showing the wrong way to do this.

Answer (score 407):

There are a few ways to do this:

**1) Get values from array of form elements by index**

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(event.target[0].value)
}
```

**2) Using *name* attribute in html**

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(event.target.elements.username.value) // from elements property
  console.log(event.target.username.value)          // or directly
}

<input type="text" name="username"/>
```

**3) Using refs**

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
  console.log(this.inputNode.value)
}

<input type="text" name="username" ref={node => (this.inputNode = node)}/>
```

Full example

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(event.target[0].value)
    console.log(event.target.elements.username.value)
    console.log(event.target.username.value)
    console.log(this.inputNode.value)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input
            type="text"
            name="username"
            ref={node => (this.inputNode = node)}
          />
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Option **2** doesn't work for me. There is no property "elements" nor "username", even though my input's name is "username"

Comment: @Madacol this may happen is you have a few inputs with the same name

Comment: Option 2 is the best answer. Getting the elements via `getElementById` is simply redundant if you already have the `event` param.

Comment: @Madacol, try using `event.target.form.username.value`.
This worked for me.

Answer (score 66):

Adding on to [Michael Schock's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427384/get-form-data-in-react/47479784#47479784):

```
class MyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(event.target);

    console.log(data.get('email')); // Reference by form input's `name` tag

    fetch('/api/form-submit-url', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="username">Enter username</label>
        <input id="username" name="username" type="text" />

        <label htmlFor="email">Enter your email</label>
        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" />

        <label htmlFor="birthdate">Enter your birth date</label>
        <input id="birthdate" name="birthdate" type="text" />

        <button>Send data!</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

[See this Medium article: How to Handle Forms with Just React](https://medium.com/@everdimension/how-to-handle-forms-with-just-react-ac066c48bd4f)

This method gets form data only when the Submit button is pressed. It is much cleaner, IMO!

Comment: This also prevent's re-rendering the form on continuous state changes!

Comment: If you do not need to access the form data before submitting, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 63):

For those who don't want to use ref and reset the state with `OnChange` event, you can just use simple OnSubmit handle and loop through the `FormData` object.

Note that you cannot access `formData.entries()` directly since it is an iterable, you have to loop over it.

This example is using React Hooks:

```
const LoginPage = () => {
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
    event.preventDefault();
    for (let [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
      console.log(key, value);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And if you're using TypeScript:

```
export const LoginPage: React.FC<{}> = () => {
  const handleSubmit: React.FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> = (event) => {
    const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
    event.preventDefault();
    for (let [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
      console.log(key, value);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Great answer, but a nitpick could you remove the var otherwise perfect solution!

Comment: can anybody help me with a typescript variant of this code snippet above?

Comment: `new FormData(event.target)` gives `{}` for me

Comment: @tejasvi88 you need to call entries on the FormData object. Not all JS objects will reveal their contents upon logging.

Comment: @Joseph My form actually didn't have name attributes.

Comment: Great answer, helped me a lot! Can you tell me though how to get checkbox values using this method as `true | false`? I'm getting `'on' | undefined` instead.

Answer (score 54):

There isn't any need to use refs. You can access it using an event:

```
function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const {username, password } = e.target.elements
    console.log({username: username.value, password: password.value })
}

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
   <input type="text" id="username"/>
   <input type="text" id="password"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Comment: great, this is what I was looking for thank you

Comment: what does elements do? couldn't find anything about e.target.elements

Comment: Any way to avoid the id duplication?

Comment: @tejasvi88 you can check my method to avoid id

Comment: Great Sameera - this is easy to understand coming from vanilla js. thanks

Answer (score 51):

An alternative approach is to use the `ref` attribute and reference the values with `this.refs`. Here is a simple example:

```
render: function() {
    return (<form onSubmit={this.submitForm}>
        <input ref="theInput" />
    </form>);
},
submitForm: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(React.findDOMNode(this.refs.theInput).value);
}
```

More info can be found in the React docs:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-string-attribute

For a lot of the reasons described in [How do I use radio buttons in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694078/how-do-i-use-radio-buttons-in-react) this approach isn't always the best, but it does present a useful alternative in some simple cases.

Comment: Does this solution is really better and wasn't available at question time, or it's a "ugly" way?

Comment: actually you don't need React.findDOMNode this.refs.theInput already an html node

Comment: refs is depreciated, this answer no longer holds.

Answer (score 24):

An easy way to deal with refs:

```javascript
class UserInfo extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = {};
    for (const field in this.refs) {
      formData[field] = this.refs[field].value;
    }
    console.log('-->', formData);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input ref="phone" className="phone" type='tel' name="phone"/>
            <input ref="email" className="email" type='tel' name="email"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
          </form>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default UserInfo;
```

Comment: This method will someday in the future be deprecated. Refs are to only used with callbacks and not strings. For more details: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Cool! :) I like to use `Object.keys()` followed for `map()` like this: `Object.keys(this.refs).map(field => formData[field] = this.refs[field].value)`

Comment: Yes the string refs are deprecated.
A better way to do it right now is to use the onChange callback.
If you still want to use refs you could use this synctax:
`<input type="text" ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }} />`

Comment: I @E.Fortes, can you please explain the onChange callback method? Thank you very much if you will. Please tag me so I will be informed of your answer.

Comment: a simple way would be (sorry the code formatter not working):

class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

Comment: You *might* want to use the `FormData` object instead of `{}`.

Answer (score 21):

You could switch the `onClick` event handler on the button to an `onSubmit` handler on the form:

```
render : function() {
      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleLogin}>
          <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
          <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
          <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
      );
    },
```

Then you can make use of `FormData` to parse the form (and construct a JSON object from its entries if you want).

```
handleLogin: function(e) {
   const formData = new FormData(e.target)
   const user = {}

   e.preventDefault()

   for (let entry of formData.entries()) {
       user[entry[0]] = entry[1]
   }

   // Do what you will with the user object here
}
```

Comment: Running this plus 'console.log(user);' gives an object with no usable value ! Any opinion ?

Comment: @MahdiRafatjah ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ - it works in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mschock/exvko2Lf/

Comment: a friend of mine referred me to react document and they are doing it like this https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: nice, that seems much cleaner =)

Comment: No need for for loop:
"const values = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());"

Answer (score 17):

If all your inputs / textarea have a name, then you can filter all from event.target:

```
onSubmit(event){
  const fields = Array.prototype.slice.call(event.target)
      .filter(el => el.name)
      .reduce((form, el) => ({
        ...form,
        [el.name]: el.value,
      }), {})
}
```

Totally uncontrolled form  without onChange methods, value, defaultValue...

Answer (score 13):

I would suggest the following approach:

```
import {Autobind} from 'es-decorators';

export class Form extends Component {

    @Autobind
    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
    }

    @Autobind
    add(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.collection.add(this.state);
        this.refs.form.reset();
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate() {
        return false;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.add} ref="form">
                <input type="text" name="desination" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                <input type="date" name="startDate" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                <input type="date" name="endDate" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                <textarea name="description" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                <button type="submit">Add</button>
            </form>
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: If you'r not rerendering the component, how you can set the value of each element according to the current state? e.g "value={this.state. destination}". Also you can't run react validations on the form if your not rerendering it

Answer (score 12):

Here is the shortest way to get data from the form and the best way to avoid id and ref just by using FormData:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class FormComponent extends Component {
  formSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    var data = new FormData(event.target)
    let formObject = Object.fromEntries(data.entries())
    console.log(formObject)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.formSubmit}>
          <label>Name</label>
          <input name="name" placeholder="name" />
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" />
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default FormComponent
```

Comment: Simplest solution here

Answer (score 6):

More clear example with [es6 destructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Computed_object_property_names_and_destructuring)

```
class Form extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            login: null,
            password: null,
            email: null
        }
    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let login = this.state.login;
        let password = this.state.password;
        // etc
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
                <input type="text" name="login" onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} />
                <input type="password" name="password" onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} />
                <input type="email" name="email" onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} />
                <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Re "destructing": Not [destructuring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)#Parallel_assignment)?

Answer (score 6):

For TypeScript users

```
import react from 'react'

interface FormInterface {
    [key: string]: string
}

const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
   event.preventDefault();
   let formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget)
   let formObj: FormInterface = {}
   for (let [key, value] of Array.from(formData.entries())) {
     formObj[key] = value.toString()
   }
};

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
   <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
   <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
   <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 6):

[TypeScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript) will complain if you try [Aliaksandr Sushkevich's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427384/get-form-data-in-react/47678799#47678799). One workaround can be done using type assertions:

```html
<form
    onSubmit={(e: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const target = e.target as typeof e.target & {
        username: { value: string };
        password: { value: string };
      };
      const username = target.username.value; // typechecks
      const password = target.password.value; // typechecks
      // etc...
    }}
>
<input type="text" name="username"/>
...
```

Though, this is still just a workaround, because here you are telling TypeScript what to expect. This will break at runtime if you add a value that doesn't have a corresponding input element.

Answer (score 5):

Give your inputs ref like this

```html
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" ref="email" />
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" ref="password" />
```

Then you can access it in your handleLogin like so:

```
handleLogin: function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.refs.email.value)
    console.log(this.refs.password.value)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I use like this using React Component state:

```html
<input type="text" name='value' value={this.state.value} onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)} />

handleChange(e){
   this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}`
```

Comment: There is only one [backtick](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/backtick#Noun). What is the intent?

Answer (score 4):

Also, this can be used too.

```
handleChange: function(state,e) {
  this.setState({[state]: e.target.value});
},
render : function() {
  return (
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'email')} />
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'password')}/>
      <button type="button" onClick={this.handleLogin}>Login</button>
    </form>
  );
},
handleLogin: function() {
  console.log("EMail: ", this.state.email);
  console.log("Password: ", this.state.password);
}
```

Comment: Please include an explanation for why this answer is the correct way to go.

Comment: I use only one method to change text form

Comment: The password can be seen in react dev tools, bit of a security issue?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using [Redux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redux_(JavaScript_library)) in your project, you can consider using the higher order component *[redux-form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form)*.

Answer (score 4):

In many events in JavaScript, we have `event` which gives an object, including what event happened and what are the values, etc.

That's what we use with forms in React as well.

So in your code you set the state to the new value. Something like this:

```
class UserInfo extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
  }

  handleLogin(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    for (const field in this.refs) {
      this.setState({this.refs[field]: this.refs[field].value});
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleLogin}>
            <input ref="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
            <input ref="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
            <button type="button">Login</button>
          </form>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default UserInfo;
```

Also this is the form example in React v.16, just as reference for the form you creating in the future:

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This might help [Meteor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteor_%28web_framework%29) (v1.3) users:

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.submitForm.bind(this)}>
            <input type="text" ref="email" placeholder="Email" />
            <input type="password" ref="password" placeholder="Password" />
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    );
},
submitForm: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log( this.refs.email.value );
    console.log( this.refs.password.value );
}
```

Comment: this.submitForm.bind(this) should be just: this.submitForm

Comment: Error: Stateless function components cannot have refs.

Comment: Are you using Meteor (v1.3) ?

Answer (score 3):

To improve the user experience; when the user clicks on the submit button, you can try to get the form to first show a sending message. Once we've received a response from the server, it can update the message accordingly. We achieve this in React by chaining statuses. See [codepen](http://codepen.io/hom_bahrani/pen/pPpOGP?editors=0011) or snippets below:

The following method makes the first state change:

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ message: 'Sending...' }, this.sendFormData);
}
```

As soon as React shows the above Sending message on screen, it will call the method that will send the form data to the server: this.sendFormData(). For simplicity I've added a setTimeout to mimic this.

```
sendFormData() {
  var formData = {
      Title: this.refs.Title.value,
      Author: this.refs.Author.value,
      Genre: this.refs.Genre.value,
      YearReleased: this.refs.YearReleased.value};
  setTimeout(() => { 
    console.log(formData);
    this.setState({ message: 'data sent!' });
  }, 3000);
}
```

In React, the method this.setState() renders a component with new properties. So you can also add some logic in render() method of the form component that will behave differently depending on the type of response we get from the server. For instance:

```
render() {
  if (this.state.responseType) {
      var classString = 'alert alert-' + this.state.type;
      var status = <div id="status" className={classString} ref="status">
                     {this.state.message}
                   </div>;
  }
return ( ...
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/hom_bahrani/pen/pPpOGP?editors=0011)

Answer (score 3):

```
 onChange(event){
     console.log(event.target.value);
  }
  handleSubmit(event){ 
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = {};
      for (const data in this.refs) {
        formData[data] = this.refs[data].value;
      }
    console.log(formData);
  }



 <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
  <input type="text" ref="username" onChange={this.onChange} className="form-control"/>
  <input type="text" ref="password" onChange={this.onChange} className="form-control"/>
  <button type="submit" className="btn-danger btn-sm">Search</button>
 </form>
```

[Output image attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsvRX.png)

Comment: Please provide an explanation as well.

Comment: I'll try to explain this, which I found brilliant.
In the handleSubmit() function you are building an object (formData) in which the key is the 'ref' attribute of every input in the form (the 'formData[data]' statement), and the value is the value of the input with this 'ref' attribute (the 'this.refs[data].value' statement). 
With 'formData[data] = this.refs[data].value' you are building this object. 
You are saying, literally:
formData['username'] = (the value of username input) and formData['password'] = (the value of password input)
Output will be: {user: 'blablabla', password: 'xxx'}

Comment: Thank you @SimonaAdriani for you explanation .

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of dynamically added fields. Here form data will store by input name key using a React **useState** hook.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function AuthForm({ firebase }) {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});

    // On Form Submit
    const onFormSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('data', formData)
        // Submit here
    };

    // get Data
    const getData = (key) => {
        return formData.hasOwnProperty(key) ? formData[key] : '';
    };

    // Set data
    const setData = (key, value) => {
        return setFormData({ ...formData, [key]: value });
    };

    console.log('firebase', firebase)
    return (
        <div className="wpcwv-authPage">
            <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit} className="wpcwv-authForm">
                <input name="name" type="text" className="wpcwv-input" placeholder="Your Name" value={getData('name')} onChange={(e) => setData('name', e.target.value)} />
                <input name="email" type="email" className="wpcwv-input" placeholder="Your Email" value={getData('email')} onChange={(e) => setData('email', e.target.value)} />
                <button type="submit" className="wpcwv-button wpcwv-buttonPrimary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AuthForm
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution that came to my mind is this:

```html
<form onSubmit={(e) => handleLogin(e)}>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Your handle fuction:

```
const handleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const data = {
        email: e.target.elements.email.value,
        password: e.target.elements.password.value
    }
    console.log('FormData: ', data)
}
```

When you click on your login button you will see FormData in console in this format:
`FormData: {email: 'whatever you tiped here', password: 'also whatever you tiped here'}`.

`e.target.elements.email.value` targets elements with specific name, in your case it is email and password.

After `console.log` in `handleLogin`, you can do some verification logic and login logic.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple occurrences of an element name, then you have to use forEach().

**HTML**

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="delete" id="flizzit" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="delete" id="floo" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="delete" id="flum" />
  <input type="submit" value="Save"  onClick={evt => saveAction(evt)}></input>
```

**JavaScript**

```
const submitAction = (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  const dels = evt.target.parentElement.delete;
  const deleted = [];
  dels.forEach((d) => { if (d.checked) deleted.push(d.id); });
  window.alert(deleted.length);
};
```

Note the dels in this case is a RadioNodeList, not an array, and is not an Iterable. The *forEach()* is a built-in method of the list class. You will not be able to use a map() or reduce() here.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

```javascript
const handleLogin = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.target[0].value)
    console.log(event.target[1].value)
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
const HandleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let formData = e.target[0].form;
        axios({
            url: 'http://localhost:4000/data/add',
            method: 'POST',
            data: new FormData(formData)
        }).then(async (data) => {
            await toastr.success('Added Successfully', {
                timeOut: 1000,
            });
            await setTimeout(() => {
                window.location.reload();
            }, 1000)

        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is also the answer that you need. In addition, Here I add the required attributes. onChange attributes of Each input components are functions. You need to add your own logic there.

```
handleEmailChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({email: e.target.value});
},
handlePasswordChange: function(e) {
   this.setState({password: e.target.value});
},
formSubmit : async function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Form submit Logic
  },
render : function() {
      return (
        <form onSubmit={(e) => this.formSubmit(e)}>
          <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleEmailChange} required />
          <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handlePasswordChange} required />
          <button type="button">Login</button>
        </form>);
},
handleLogin: function() {
    //Login Function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be the easiest method:

```
const formValidator = (form) => {
    let returnData = {}
    console.log(form.length);

    for (let i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
        const data = form[i]
        if (data.name != null && data.name != "") {
            returnData[data.name] = data.value;
        }
    }
    return returnData
}
```

In the form, simply use:

```html
<form onSubmit={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        let data = formValidator(e.currentTarget)
    }}>
    <RoundTextFiled name='app-id' style={{ marginTop: '10px', borderRadius: '20px' }} label="App id" fullWidth required />
    <RoundTextFiled name='api-hash' style={{ marginTop: '5px' }} label="Api hash" fullWidth required />
    <RoundTextFiled name='channel-id' style={{ marginTop: '5px' }} label="Channel id" fullWidth required />
    <Button type='submit' variant="contained" fullWidth style={{ padding: '10px', marginTop: '5px', borderRadius: '10px' }}>Login</Button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach for collecting multiple form inputs using single `inputChangeHandler`

```
import React from "react";

const COLORS = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "purple", "green", "white", "black"];

export default function App() {

  const initialFormFields = {
    name: undefined,
    email: undefined,
    favourite_color: undefined
  };
  const [formInput, setFormInput] = React.useState(initialFormFields);

  function inputChangeHandler(event) {
    setFormInput(prevFormState => ({
      ...prevFormState,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    }))
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
        <label>Name: <input name="name" type="text" value={formInput.name} onChange={inputChangeHandler}/></label>
        <label>Email: <input name="email" type="email" value={formInput.email} onChange={inputChangeHandler}/></label>
        <div>
          {COLORS.map(color => <label><input type="radio" name="favourite_color" value={color} key={color} onChange={inputChangeHandler}/> {color} </label>)}
        </div>
      </form>

      <div>
        Entered Name: {formInput.name}
        Entered Email: {formInput.email}
        Favourite Color: {formInput.favourite_color}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using React 18, this approach would make it for you:

```
export default function Search() {
  function search(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("search clicked data = " + e.target[0].value);
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={search}>
      <input name="query" />
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

the official documentation does not work but here is a reference in case in the future they will fix it:
https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/form#handle-form-submission-on-the-client

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState({})

    const updateData = e => {
        setData({
            ...data,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    const submit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(data)
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={submit}>
            <input
                name="email"
                type="email"
                onChange={updateData}
            />
            <input
                name="password"
                type="password"
                onChange={updateData}
             />
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).