# React GET form data on submit

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

I'm new to React and I've been facing a problem since few hours now. Even if I found some topics on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427384/get-form-data-in-reactjs) or Google that seems equivalent to my issue, I'm unable to solve it...

I'm using [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) to create a simple form. For now, I have only one multi-select input. I am able to use it as expected but when I press "Submit" I want to retrieve the values selected. I tried with `refs`, with `onChange` without success. `onChange` is never fired, that might be an other issue as well.

```
var MultiSelect = React.createClass({
    onLabelClick: function (data, event) {
        console.log(data, event);
    },

    render: function() {
      var ops = []

      this.props.categories.forEach(function(category) {
      ops.push({ label: category.name, value: category.id });
    });

        return (
            <div>
                <Select
                    name = {this.props.name}
                    delimiter=" "
                    multi={true}
                    allowCreate={true}
                    placeholder = {this.props.label}
                    options={ops} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});


var ProductForm = React.createClass({
  submit: function () {
    console.log("Categories: " + this.state.categories);
  },

  onCategoryChange: function(e) {
    console.log("CATEGORY CHANGED !!!!!!")
    this.setState({categories: e.target.value});
    },

  render: function () {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.submit}>
        <MultiSelect label="Choose a Category" name="categories" categories={this.props.categories} onChange={this.onCategoryChange}/>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
});
```

PS : data `categories` comes from a Rails controller.

Comment: have you checked your console or debugger what errors you get?

Comment: @hyphenbash There is no logs (infos or errors) displayed on the console

Comment: one observation is that you haven't initialized your categories and other props in getInitialState method, hence no initial state specified.

Comment: if you provide initial state then also you need to change your multiselect directive with this: categories={this.state.categories} where your categories are already initialized

Answer (score 0):

I believe your internal `Select` component should receive `onChange` from the `props` provided to `MultiSelect`, assuming your intention is to listen to changes on the `Select` component.

Try something like this inside your `MultiSelect`'s `render()` method:

```
return (
    <div>
        <Select
            name = {this.props.name}
            delimiter=" "
            multi={true}
            allowCreate={true}
            placeholder = {this.props.label}
            options={ops} 
            onChange={this.props.onChange} />
    </div>
);
```

Side note, I don't think `e.target.value` is going to work inside `onCategoryChange`, since `react-select` doesn't send standard events.