# How to collect values from a form in react.js?

Tags: reactjs

I am new in react.js. I am trying to collect values from a Form. I read several SO question and article found from Google search. I am confused now. **Which one is the actual way of collecting values from a Form in react.js** ? 
I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427384/get-form-data-in-reactjs) SO question. I found here

```
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleEmailChange} />
```

I read [this](https://blog.stvmlbrn.com/2017/04/07/submitting-form-data-with-react.html) article and found below code

```
<input type="text" name="fname" value={fname} onChange={this.onChange} />
```

In a Facebook group, members advised me to use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formik).

Which way should I follow ? Should I use `state` ?

Comment: you need to use 1st approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple form, you don't need to use Formik.

`<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleEmailChange} />` is the correct way to do it.

In response to

> how can I catch the value inside a function

You need to create a method in your class

```
handleEmailChange(e) {
    let val = e.target.value;
}
```

`val` contains the value of the input.

Or even easier is to just get it from `this.state.email`.

Comment: Thanks @OI' Reliable. After this how can I catch the value inside a function ? Thanks.