# Recommendations to get React input test

Tags: reactjs

What is the most efficient way to get the text in an input?

I know I can have it like this

```
handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
};

<Input onChange = {this.handleChange}/>
```

Wouldn't this cause performance issues since I'm updating the state (which causes a rerender) every time a change is made to the input? Should I write a `shouldComponentUpdate` method to stop it from rerendering?

Also, is there a way to get what is inside the Input only when a button is clicked?

Comment: I think you're looking something like this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/47678799/2845389

Comment: Any thoughts about the answers?

Answer (score 1):

You have some options:

1. Use `onBlur` instead of `onChange` so it will happen only when the user "leaves" the input
2. Use `debounce` like [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1360#issuecomment-333969294) one.

But it depends on the experience and the ui impact of that change. I mean, if you need immediate impact (you present the value somewhere else in the UI), I don't think you have a choice.

If not, and you case is standart `form` (or `form` like), you can listen to `onSubmit` and extract the values from the `form`, something like this:

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const values = Array.from(e.target.elements).reduce((old, current) => {
      if (current.attributes.name) {
        old[current.name] = current.value
      }
      return old;
    }, {})
    this.setState(values);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input name="name" placeholder="name" />
          <input name="email" placeholder="email" />
          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
        <hr />
        <pre>
          {
            JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 2)
          }
        </pre>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ewpsla

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) or use one of the UI libraries like [ant-design](https://ant.design/components/input/) to have better input and form management.

```
class CustomTextInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // create a ref to store the textInput DOM element
    this.textInput = React.createRef();
    this.focusTextInput = this.focusTextInput.bind(this);
  }

  focusTextInput() {
    // Explicitly focus the text input using the raw DOM API
    // Note: we're accessing "current" to get the DOM node
    this.textInput.current.focus();
  }

  render() {
    // tell React that we want to associate the <input> ref
    // with the `textInput` that we created in the constructor
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          ref={this.textInput} />

        <input
          type="button"
          value="Focus the text input"
          onClick={this.focusTextInput}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, every `keypress` will change the state and will re-render the component.

But, as react compares the virtually created DOM before rendering, it will only re-render the Input field to browser in your case.

If you want to avoid that too, You should create small small components extending from `PureComponent`. PureComponent implements `shouldComponentUpdate` internally. That way it will re-render only Input field leaving other components as it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ref` to get value of Input. Here is example how you can do it. I have added to get value and to clear value

```
class CustomTextInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.textInput = null;
  }


  getValue = () => {
    console.log(this.textInput.value)
  }

  clearValue = () => {
    this.textInput.value = ""
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          ref={el => this.textInput = el} 
        />


        <input
          type="button"
          value="Get Value"
          onClick={this.getValue}
        />

        <input
          type="button"
          value="Clear Value"
          onClick={this.clearValue}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CustomTextInput;
```