# TypeScript React: Get form values with useRef

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to post whatever values are in the form to the API, im using useRef to get the form like this...

```
  const formElement = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);
```

Submit function

```
  const submit = async (event: React.FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const body = new URLSearchParams(new FormData(formElement.current)); // <=== error
    const response = await fetch(baseUrl, { body, method: 'post'});
  };
```

and the form

```
<form onSubmit={submit} ref={formElement}>
   <input type='text' id='test' value='testValue'/>
</form>
```

The error I get is in the console, then it fails to compile

`Argument of type 'HTMLFormElement | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLFormElement | undefined'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLFormElement | undefined'.ts(2345)`

The entire component is here...

```
     <Poster
        method='post'
        baseUrl='https://api.funge.it/join'
        auth={false}
        keys='email, fullName, password, username'
      />


import React, { useContext, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { BEARER_TOKEN, Dispatch, Global } from '../globalState';

interface PropsInterface {
  auth: boolean;
  baseUrl: string;
  keys: string;
  method: string;
}

const Poster: React.FC<PropsInterface> = (props: PropsInterface) => {
  const { global } = useContext(Global);
  const { dispatch } = useContext(Dispatch);

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    auth: props.auth,
    baseUrl: props.baseUrl,
    keys: props.keys.split(','),
    method: props.method,
  });
  const { auth, baseUrl, keys, method } = state;
  const { bearer } = global;
  const baseUrlRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  // const formElement = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);
  // const formElement = useRef<HTMLFormElement | null>();
  // const formElement = useRef<HTMLFormElement | undefined>();
  const formElement = React.useRef() as React.MutableRefObject<HTMLFormElement>;

  const submit = async (event: React.FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, loading: true }));
    const body = new URLSearchParams(new FormData(formElement.current));
    const response = await fetch(baseUrl, { body, method });
    const content = await response.json();
    setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, response, loading: false }));
    if (response.status === 200 && content.jwtToken) {
      dispatch({ type: BEARER_TOKEN, value: content.jwtToken });
    }
  };
  const copy = (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (baseUrlRef.current) baseUrlRef.current.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    const button = event.target as HTMLButtonElement;
    button.focus();
  };

  return (
    <form className='poster' onSubmit={submit} ref={formElement}>
      <div className='poster--where'>
        <div className='poster--where-container-method'>
          <div className='poster--method'>{method}</div>
          <input type='text' value={baseUrl} ref={baseUrlRef} readOnly className='poster--url' />
        </div>
        <div className='poster--where-container-actions'>
          <button className='poster--send'>Send</button>
          <button className='poster--copy' onClick={copy}>
            Copy
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      {auth && (
        <div className='poster--auth'>
          <div className='poster--auth-type'>Bearer Token</div>
          <input type='text' value={bearer} readOnly className='poster--url' />
        </div>
      )}
      {keys.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div className='poster--keys-values'>
            <div className='poster--key-title'>{item}:</div>
            <input
              type='text'
              id={item}
              key={index}
              className='poster--value-title'
            />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </form>
  );
};

export { Poster };
```

UPDATE Natarich J I now get this error in the ref on the input

```
I so wish it did but i now get an error in the ref part of the input
`Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLFormElement | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HTMLFormElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLFormElement> | null | undefined'.
  Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLFormElement | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLFormElement>'.
    Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
      Type 'HTMLFormElement | undefined' is not assignable to type 'HTMLFormElement | null'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'HTMLFormElement | null'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(106, 9): The expected type comes from property 'ref' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<FormHTMLAttributes<HTMLFormElement>, HTMLFormElement>'`
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41198567/982311

Comment: Is it not possible with useRef?

Comment: Output when console logging `formElement.current`

Comment: the TypeScript won't even compile, I can't get an output unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

The error log basically says there was a type mismatch. It is likely because you assigned `null` to `formElement`.

Since `FormData` only receives data of type either `HTMLFormElement` or `undefined`. But you assigned `null` to `formElement` which indicates `formElement` is also of type `null`, which basically means the following:

```
typeof formElement                 ===> <HTMLFormElement> || null
typeof data_that_FormData_receives ===> <HTMLFormElement> || undefined
```

You see there is a mismatch. So probably the solution is

```
# I forgot whether should be '|' or '||', play around with it...

const formElement = useRef<HTMLFormElement || undefined>();
```

Tell me if it works

---

Update:

Also you should not need `new URLSearchParams()`, just do this instead

```
const body = new FormData(formElement.current)
```

Comment: it was single pipe | but I get a new error ... `Argument of type 'FormData' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | string[][] | Record<string, string> | URLSearchParams | undefined'.
  Property 'sort' is missing in type 'FormData' but required in type 'URLSearchParams'.ts(2345)`
lib.dom.d.ts(16068, 5): 'sort' is declared here.

Comment: @Bill This is because the `formdata` you get from `new FormData(data)` is of type `FormData`, which is not a valid type for being the parameters of `URLSearchParams`.

Comment: maybe `new URLSearchParams()` is not needed? would just `const body = new FormData(formElement.current);` work?

Comment: @Bill  Since you will pass it as the body of a post request, then yes you don't need to `new URLSearchParams()`, just use `new FormData()` shall work

Comment: please can you show me how to convert the formdata, I don't fully understand your comment above

Comment: @Bill Please see my update there and tell me if it works :)

Comment: @Bill is duplicating your errors. Please wait for a while

Comment: @Bill Did you try run your code without `new URLSearchParams()`, as I said in the answer, cuz I saw it was still there in your code? Also there is an almost same problem discussed [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/35572). You may have a look at it if it still does not work after you delete `new URLSearchParams()`

Comment: yes I tried removing new URLSearchParams() but get a bigger error I added to the initial post as an update