# what is the difference between onSubmit={onSubmit} vs onSubmit={() => onSubmit()}

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am pretty new to js so i have an confusion over when to use which type of call, any help or any link would be great

for example while submiting a form i was using onSubmit={() => onSubmit()} but it doesn't work while i changed that to onSubmit={onSubmit()} it works

```
const onSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const credentials = {
            emailAddress: email.trim(),
            password: password,
            rememberMe: rememberMe,
        };
        if (!emailError && email && password) {
            setLoading(true);
            login(credentials)
                .then((result) => {
                    setLoading(false);
                    if (result) {
                        setError(false);
                        window.location.assign('/');
                    } else {
                        setError(t('Login.InvalidCredentials'));
                    }
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    setError(t('Login.ServerError'));
                    setLoading(false);
                });
        }
    };
 

     <Form fontColor={(props) => props.theme.colors.grey.base} onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                    <Loader visibility={loading} />
                    <LoginDiv>
                        <Label>{t('E-mail')}</Label>
                        <Input
                            id={'email'}
                            type={'email'}
                            placeholder={'johndoe@email.com'}
                            value={email}
                            onChange={(e) => emailValidation(e.target.value)}
                        />
                        <Status>{emailError}</Status>
                    </LoginDiv>
    
     <PasswordDiv>
                        <Label>{t('Password')}</Label>
                        <Input
                            id={'password'}
                            placeholder={'●●●●●●●●●●●●●●'}
                            value={password}
                            onChange={(e) => handlePassword(e)}
                            onKeyPress={() => handleKeyPress()}
                        />
                        <IconDiv>
                            <Eye onClick={() => setShow(!showPassword)} />
                        </IconDiv>
                    </PasswordDiv>
    
                    <Column>
                        <ForgetText
                            onClick={() => props.history.push('/forgot_password')}
                        >
                            {t('Login.Forgotten')}
                        </ForgetText>
                        <Remember>
                            <label>
                                <Input
                                    type={'checkbox'}
                                    onClick={() => setRemeber(!rememberMe)}
                                    value={rememberMe}
                                />
                                {t('Login.Remember')}
                            </label>
                        </Remember>
                    </Column>
                    <Button
                        type='submit'
                    >
                        {t('Sign In')}
                    </Button>
                  </Form>
```

so why it is working now and why not working when using it in this way (onSubmit={() => onSubmit()}), i don't know why and when to use which any help would be much appriciated, or any links where i get to know about this and usage thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you mean `onSubmit={onSubmit()}` or `onSubmit={onSubmit}`?

Comment: `onSubmit={onSubmit()}` would and most probably is sending the form right after it gets rendered. Anyway, the `onSubmit={onSubmit}` is almost the same as `onSubmit={() => onSubmit()}`. The difference between these two is the component is recreating the same function every render in second case.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an issue with passing arguments to the handler function.
`() => onSubmit()` calls the function without passing arguments, while `onSubmit={onSubmit}` tells what function should be called, and the arguments (form data) are passed to it.
This answer may help you deciding which way to handle the data: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47678799/5815359)

Answer (score 1):

1. `onSubmit={onSubmit}` would pass whatever arguments the form adds to `onSubmit(...args)` while `onSubmit={() => onSubmit()}` wouldn't pass any arguments to `onSubmit` function.
2. `onSubmit={() => onSubmit()}` would create the function `() => onSubmit()` every-time the component is re-rendered.

Note that if you do like this `onSubmit={onSubmit()}`, it will be called every single time the component renders/re-renders which is not what you most probably want.

Answer (score 1):

```js
onSubmit={onSubmit}
```

and

```js
onSubmit={() => onSubmit()}
```

Both do the same thing. However

```js
onSubmit={onSubmit()}
```

will execute on every render even without clicking.

Answer (score 0):

Your onSubmit function requires the argument `e`, since the first thing you call is `e.preventDefault()`.

If you have this:

```
onSubmit={() => onSubmit()}
```

...you are calling the function without the argument `e`. This will throw a runtime error.

You can fix this runtime error with:

```
onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}
```

Or, to make that line a little cleaner:

```
onSubmit={onSubmit}
```

Hope that helps explain the difference!