# Manage with React api query useState Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-query

After creating useState Hook
For gender, age useState('30');
useState('female');
If you set

```
http://api.minsu.com/product/${id}?gender=feamle&age=30
```

I am using react-query(useQuery) for api state management library.
It's no different, I'm creating a dynamic page right now and then showing the page based on the id value.

This is an example.

```
https://api.minsu.com/product/${id}
```

And on the detailed page, `http://api.minsu.com/product/${id}?gender=feamle&age=30` In this way, random data is entered for gender and age, and only specific data of a 30-year-old woman is shown.

select box (option)
After choosing female and age as
Set the api to `https://api.minsu.com/product/${id}?gender=${gender}&age=${age}`
I want to show the detail page after receiving gender and age through api get according to the selected select by modifying it in this way.

It seems that I am not directly using input and select box, and I do not know how to write query using useState Hook.

But I don't know what to do.

This is my code now.

I thought about it for about an hour.
I have created age and gender with setState('').

```
    const [gender, setGenders] = useState('female');
    const [age, setAges] = useState('30');


   const fetchDetail = async () => {
        const res = await 
        fetch(`https://api.minsu.com/product/${id}?gender=${female}&age=${age}`, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
            withCredentials: true 
        });
        return res.json();
    }

    const { data: ProductDetail, status, error, isFetching } = useQuery('productDetail', fetchDetail, {
        notifyOnChangeProps: ['data'], 
        staleTime: 100000000,
    })
    console.log(ProductDetail);

return (
 

 <input type="number" placeholder={Enter your age} .... />
 <button onClick={onClick} />
 

 <option>Select gender</option>
    <option value="male">Male</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
)
```

That is, to summarize

```
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
        age: '30',
        gender: 'female',
    })
    const {age, gender} = inputs; 

    const onChange = (e) =>{ 
        setInputs({ ...inputs, [e.target.age]:e.target.value }) 
    }

  return (
 <input name="age" onChange={onChange} placeholder = "age"/> 
            <input name="gender" onChange={onChange} placeholder = "gender"/>

)
```

I want to change the query by executing onChange after creating the input, but the rendering is not working.

Comment: Is the issue that the URL that gets fetched doesn't update when you update the form?

Comment: @HenryWoody Yes, that's right.
How to update the query after receiving age and gender as input(age), gender(selectbox)

Comment: Is this the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69834291/react-enter-as-api-optional-state-gender-gender? In either case it's still unclear what the issue is. If I had to take a guess after looking at the useQuery docs, you need to update the `queryKey` argument to trigger the hook.

Comment: @DrewReese I don't know if I need to change the query to setState with age and gender.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get form data in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427384/get-form-data-in-reactjs)

Comment: @HenryWoody How do I change the query value when onSubmit of form age and gender?

Comment: The link I provided above should answer your question, basically you need to connect your form and your state. I'd go with the accepted answer (not the highest voted) because it's the most straightforward and works best for this usecase (albeit using class components). See also [React Forms](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html). If your state variables update according to the form, the URL will update automatically as well. Also you have a typo, you need to swap `gender=${female}` with `gender=${gender}`.

Comment: What part are you stuck on? You still haven't clarified what the issue is.

Comment: I don't know if I need to change the query to setState with age and gender.   ```code const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
        age: '30',
        gender: 'female',
    })
    const {age, gender} = inputs; 

    const onChange = (e) =>{ 
        setInputs({ ...inputs, [e.target.age]:e.target.value }) 
    } 
            <input name="age" onChange={onChange} placeholder = "age"/> 
            <input name="gender" onChange={onChange} placeholder = "gender"/>
 ``` 
I wrote it like this, but rendering is not working. Is the value not initialized even after rendering?

Comment: @ssksksks That looks pretty close, only issue is that you're using `e.target.age` as a key, what you want is to use the `name` of the input, like this: `setInputs({...inputs, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })`

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "change the query to setState with age and gender" but as far as the inputs and updating the `age` and `gender` state that looks close to correct, though you should use the event target's `name` property. From here I think you need to use these values as a computed query key for the `useQuery` hook.

Comment: @HenryWoody 
So how should I fix it??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're updating the local state (`age` and `gender`) correctly and just need to trigger the query again.

[Query Basics](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/queries#query-basics)

> To subscribe to a query in your components or custom hooks, call the
> useQuery hook with at least:
>
> - A **unique key for the query**
> - A function that returns a promise that:
>
>   - Resolves the data, or
>   - Throws an error

> The **unique key** you provide is used internally for refetching,
> caching, and sharing your queries throughout your application.

[If your query function depends on a variable, include it in the query key.](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-keys#if-your-query-function-depends-on-a-variable-include-it-in-your-query-key)

Given the request URL:

```
`https://api.minsu.com/product/${id}?gender=${gender}&age=${age}`
```

Then `id`, `age`, and `gender` should all probably be included as part of the query key.

```
const {
  data: ProductDetail,
  status,
  error,
  isFetching,
} = useQuery(
  ['productDetail', id, age, gender],
  fetchDetail,
  {
    notifyOnChangeProps: ['data'], 
    staleTime: 100000000,
  },
);
```

Comment: applied.
But I looked up the query key , but I don't know how to change the value of ${age} ${gender} .

Comment: @ssksksks That is what the state updates do. Can you just provide your complete code so we can see what it is you are trying to do instead of this back and forth between "Do you need help updating state?" and "Do you need help updating the query?"

Comment: I need to change the query.

But isn't it possible to change the query by changing the state?

Comment: @ssksksks On state change alone, no. You need to update the state to trigger a rerender, the updated state is essentially a dependency for the `useQuery` React hook. It hashes this "dependency" into a key so if you make the same request again and haven't invalidated the response then the request isn't made to the network, otherwise a new network request is made.

Comment: useQuery supports it! So what should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this (check my comments inside snippet):

```
import { useQueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";

const [id, setId] = useState("someId") // you don't say what should we do with id?!
const [age, setAge] = useState("30")
const [gender, setGender] = useState("female")

const onAgeChange = (e) => {
  setAge(e.target.value) // you used: e.target."""age"""!
}
const onGenderChange = (e) => {
  setGender(e.target.value) // you used: e.target."""age"""!
}

const {
  data: ProductDetail,
  status,
  error,
  isFetching,
} = useQuery(
  ['productDetail', id, age, gender],
  fetchDetail,
  {
    notifyOnChangeProps: ['data'],
    staleTime: 100000000,
  },
);

const queryClient = useQueryClient();
useEffect(() => {
  queryClient.invalidateQueries(['productDetail', id, age, gender]); // this will update your data automatically if id, age and/or gender change
}, [id, age, gender])

return (
  <>
    <input name="age" onChange={onAgeChange} value={inputs.age} placeholder="age" /> {/*  you missed the """value={}""" */}
    <input name="gender" onChange={onGenderChange} value={inputs.gender} placeholder="gender" /> {/*  you missed the """value={}""" */}
  </>
)
```