# React How to Get Value of a SelectList from a Child Component

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a form in which one of the input items will be a select list. I am trying to implement the form by using reusable components. The hierarchy is this:

```
<SignupForm>
    <CountrySelectList>
        <SelectList>
```

I am able to get the select list to render, but I am not sure how to pass the needed `props` to the child componets in order to bind the selection from the drop down list? Here are the components (with some form fields removed for brevity).

**SignupForm**

```
class SignupForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            country: ''
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("Country", this.state.country);;

        fetch("api/account/signup", {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <CountrySelectList name="country" value={this.state.country} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                <SubmitButton btnText="Submit"/>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default SignupForm;
```

**CountrySelectList**

```
class CountrySelectList extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: null,
            isLoaded: false,
            data: []
        };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('api/location/countries');
            const json = await response.json();
            this.setState({
                data: json,
                isLoaded: true
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { error, isLoaded, data } = this.state;

        if (error) {
            return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
        } else if (!isLoaded) {
            return <LoadingSpinner/>;
        } else {
            return (
                <SelectListGroup>
                    <Label label="country" title="Country"/>
                    <SelectList data={data} value={this.props.value} onChange={this.props.onChange} />
                </SelectListGroup>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default CountrySelectList;
```

**SelectList**

```
export default function SelectList({ data, value, onChange, addClass="" }) {
return (
    <select
        value={value}
        className={`form-select ${addClass}`}
        onChange={onChange}>
        {data.map((data, index) => (
            <option key={index} value={data.value}>
                {data.text}
            </option>
        ))}
    </select>
);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer has a good explanation of getting data from forms and their component parts.
[Get form data in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427384/get-form-data-in-reactjs)
You're kind of doing the same job twice by saving the selection as `state` and using `form` -> `submit`.

If you give your `select` a `name` attribute, then in the `handleSubmit` function, the event parameter will contain a named element that you can get the value from.

```
<select name='country' ...
```

Then the function can use

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.country.value);
}
```

The onSubmit event of the form carries all the info, you just have to name the elements.

Comment: Adding the `name` attribute to the `select` element fixed it for me, thank you!